# type of enumeration constants inside enumerator list in C

Tags: c, enums, embedded, keil

**EDITED**

I'm currently working on an multi-platform enumeration parser and found this weird behaviour while trying to answer the question above.

**Question A)**

Does C standard determine the type of the enumeration constants before the enumeration declaration is completed?

For Keil ARMCC, for example:

```
enum e {
    VAL0 = (signed char)126,
    VAL1,
    VAL2, 
    SIZE0 = sizeof(VAL0), 
    SIZE1 = sizeof(VAL1), 
    SIZE2 = sizeof(VAL2) 
};
```

I get SIZE0 = 1, SIZE1 = 1, SIZE2 = 8.
(if I evaluate the size of the enum constants outside the definition, all have size of int).

Shouldn't they all be equal to sizeof( int )?
(Remembering that int, in this case, has size of 4 bytes.)

**Question B)**

For Keil C251, I have the following:

```
signed int VALUE0 = (signed char)-1;
enum{ VALUE1 = (signed char)-1 };
enum{ VALUE2 = -1 };
printf( "Is VALUE0 equal to VALUE1? ---> %s", VALUE0 == VALUE1 ? "Yes!" : "No!" );
printf( "Is VALUE0 equal to VALUE2? ---> %s", VALUE0 == VALUE2 ? "Yes!" : "No!" );
```

which prints:

```
Is VALUE0 equal to VALUE1? ---> No!
Is VALUE0 equal to VALUE2? ---> Yes!
```

Shouldn't both print yes?

is there a difference between the definitions of VALUE0 and VALUE1 that I'm missing, maybe the type cast? Or is this probably a compiler bug?

Comment: This is the main reason `enum`s are not very useful for embedded systems in C: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.3p2 Note that C does not just have a specification, but a standard (ISO9899, current version is 2011, aka C11). Common advice is to use constant-like macros. Note that `const` qualified variables are still no _constants_, but – well – variables in C. Thus your variables are quite useless.

Comment: That's what I meant. I changed from specification to standard.

Comment: Note that the size of an `enum` is implementation defined, thus subject to the PCS/ABI. For ARM, see AAPCS.

Comment: Yes, but not the size of the enumeration constants.

Comment: Outside the enumerator list, sizeof(VAL0) = sizeof(VAL1) = sizeof(VAL2) = sizeof(int). My question is regarding the sizes and types inside the enumerator list, before the enumeration declaration is finished.

Comment: I don't see what usage it has to set an _enum-constant_ to the size of another. First, the standard is clear about their type and second what usage does it have? More interesting it the `sizeof` the `enum` type itself (which is ID, as I already wrote. Note also that `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, which on ARMv7 and lower is identical to `uint32_t` (typically `uint64_t` on ARM64).

Comment: Note also you should use the correct type-specifiers in the format-strings. `%hhd` would be the correct to print a `signed char` argument passed (implicitly) as `int`.

Comment: Hmm, you should read the documentation of the C251 compiler. It seem to behave not standard compilant (quite common for such small architectures). Which range does `signed char` have on that implementation? Does the architecture by any chance use 1's complement or sign/magnitude for signed integers?

Comment: I agree. But, like I wrote, I am interested on understanding how the compiler treats the enumeration constants inside the enumerator list, so I can treat them accordingly in other expressions appearing there. For example enum{V0=0xFFFFFFFF, V1} is different than enum{V0=0xFFFFFFFF, V1=V0+1}. I need to know the type of V0 to handle it properly

Comment: signed char ranges from -128 to 127 (http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_datatypes.htm), and I'm quite sure it uses 2's complement.

Comment: I had to use Keil C51 once. I am eternally grateful I don't have to now. It looks like "Keil C251" is not any improvement. I feel your pain.

Comment: You're probably better off using `#define` constants instead of enum, given these bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (unlike C++), an enumeration constant is of type `int`. It's legal to refer to an enumeration constant before the end of the type declaration.

If Keil ARMCC is giving you `sizeof(VAL0) != sizeof (int)`, where `VAL0` is an enumeration constant, then Keil ARMCC is not a conforming C compiler. I've seen other questions here that indicate that it's non-conforming.

Being non-conforming is not necessarily a compiler *bug* (unless the vendor claims that it's conforming, but as far as I know they don't).

As for part B:

```
enum e{
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_0 = (signed char)( -128 ),
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_1 = -128,
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_2 = (  signed int)(signed char)( -128 ),
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_3 = (unsigned int)(signed char)( -128 ),
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_0_PLUS_1 = MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_0 + 1,
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_1_PLUS_1 = MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_1 + 1,
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_2_PLUS_1 = MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_2 + 1,
    MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_3_PLUS_1 = MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_3 + 1,
};
```

almost any conforming C compiler should give the `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_{0,1,2}` constants the value `-128` (of type `int`), and the `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_{0,1,2}_PLUS_1` constants the value `-127` (also of type `int`). The only possible wiggle room would be for an implementation with `SCHAR_MIN == -127`, which is possible but unlikely, and apparently is *not* the case for the Keil compiler(s). If you're getting different results, either it's a bug in the compiler.

But the definition of `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_3` is problematical.  The `int` value `-128` is converted to `signed char`, which doesn't change the value. That is then converted to `unsigned int` which yields `UINT_MAX+1-128` (assuming 32 bits, this is `4294967168`). An enumeration constant with a specified value outside the range of `int` is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. (Did you get a compile-time warning?) The result, if the compiler doesn't reject the program, is undefined.

Comment: As the compiler generates the correct sizes after the `enum` definition has completed, I strongly suspect a glitch. As it is pretty useless to take the `sizeof` an _enum-constant_ during definition, they likely did not test (still it is strange behaviour from compiler construction view). Anyway, I think OP is more concerned about the other compiler.

Comment: Great, Keil!
Any idea about Question B?

Comment: @saoPaulo: Yes, the `unsigned int` cast is a problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Thompson: Hum, actually I am more concerned about MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_0 having a different value than MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_2 and c. As I understand, there should be no difference between **signed int VALUE0 = (signed char)-1** and **enum{ VALUE1 = (signed char)-1 }** regarding the values. If **VALUE0 != VALUE1**, can I affirm it is a bug?

Comment: Strictly speaking, since the definition of `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_3` is invalid (a constraint violation), the behavior of the whole program is undefined. If you delete that and still get different values for `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_0` vs. `MIN_SIGNED_CHAR_2`, then yes, I'd say that's a bug -- or at least non-conforming. But if the compiler makes enumeration constants some type other than `int`, it *might* be expected. A simpler example, perhaps with just two enumeration constants (and less confusing names than `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: @Thompson: Thank you, I updated the question. So I have non-conforming behaviour on both Keil ARMCC and C251... It will be difficult to write a parser compliant with both. I think it would be an error not to handle **(signed char)-1** properly, regardless of the chosen type for the enumeration constants, specialy when it is correctly handled for **VALUE0**. It just does not make sense for me that **VALUE1 = -1** works, but **VALUE1 = (signed char)-1** not.

Comment: @Lundin `-1` is not representable in an unsigned type. Converting to unsigned changes the value

Comment: What does the compiler's documentation say about the type and representation of enumeration constants?